# Select only top row from each set

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a problem with table below. I have to pick only users with **largest USCO_DFR** and **USCO_AHO = '1'**. So, from example below:

```
+----------+-------------------------+----------+
| USER_KEY |        USCO_DFR         | USCO_AHO |
+----------+-------------------------+----------+
|        1 | 2018-06-01 00:00:00.000 | NULL     |
|        1 | 2018-03-05 00:00:00.000 | 1        |
|        1 | 2018-02-10 00:00:00.000 | NULL     |
|        2 | 2018-07-10 00:00:00.000 | 1        |
|        2 | 2018-04-05 00:00:00.000 | NULL     |
|        2 | 2018-01-15 00:00:00.000 | NULL     |
|        3 | 2018-09-10 00:00:00.000 | 1        |
|        3 | 2018-05-05 00:00:00.000 | NULL     |
|        3 | 2018-04-15 00:00:00.000 | NULL     |
+----------+-------------------------+----------+
```

only **USER_KEY = 2,3** should be picked.

Expected output:

```
+----------+-------------------------+----------+
| USER_KEY |        USCO_DFR         | USCO_AHO |
+----------+-------------------------+----------+
|        2 | 2018-07-10 00:00:00.000 |        1 |
|        3 | 2018-09-10 00:00:00.000 |        1 |
+----------+-------------------------+----------+
```

This query sorts results:

```
SELECT * FROM @BAUSCO ORDER BY USER_KEY, USCO_DFR DESC
```

but I don't know how to pick those **USER_KEYs** from result? Basically I have to select only top row from each set, where this satisfies condition **USCO_AHO='1'**.

```
DECLARE @BAUSCO TABLE
(
    USER_KEY INT,
    USCO_DFR DATETIME,
    USCO_AHO CHAR(1)
)

INSERT @BAUSCO(USER_KEY, USCO_DFR, USCO_AHO)
VALUES (1, '2018-02-10', NULL),
(1, '2018-03-05', '1'),
(1, '2018-06-01', NULL),

(2, '2018-01-15', NULL),
(2, '2018-04-05', NULL),
(2, '2018-07-10', '1'),

(3, '2018-04-15', NULL),
(3, '2018-05-05', NULL),
(3, '2018-09-10', '1')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `ROW_NUMBER` here to target the largest `USCO_DFR` record for each user:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY USER_KEY ORDER BY USCO_DFR DESC) rn
    FROM @BAUSCO
)

SELECT USER_KEY, USCO_DFR, USCO_AHO
FROM cte
WHERE USCO_AHO = 1 and rn = 1;
```

[image]

### Demo

This will select all user records whose greatest `USCO_DFR` value is coincident with the same record for which `USCO_AHO` has a value of 1.

Comment: Only users 2,3 should be picked, because they have USCO_AHO='1' with largest USCO_DFR. Your query returs three results. See my expected output, I've added this.

Comment: Your edited query returns empty table. Have you tried it?

Comment: I think your query and your concept is great. Only this: ORDER BY USCO_DFR DESC -> so it's sorted by USCO_DFR, largest result on top.

Comment: I'm a big fan of analytic functions to clearly express what you're trying to achieve and leaving the how up to the SQL engine.  In this case, I think using row_number and order by slightly obscures the intent - you can return the max value directly.  It does raise the question of what to do with rows where the USCO_DFR values are exactly the same.

Comment: @IanMcGowan Your answer suffers from the same problem.  Should two or more records be tied for the maximum, you would get multiple results.

Answer (score 1):

you can use ROW_NUMBER with a CTE

```
;with cte as
(
select ROW_NUMBER()  over (partition by USER_KEY order by USCO_DFR desc) AS ROWNUM,*
from 
@BAUSCO
)
select USER_KEY, USCO_DFR, USCO_AHO from cte where ROWNUM=1 and USCO_AHO =1
```

Answer (score 1):

The following query should do what you want:

```
DECLARE @BAUSCO TABLE
(
    USER_KEY INT,
    USCO_DFR DATETIME,
    USCO_AHO CHAR(1)
)

INSERT @BAUSCO(USER_KEY, USCO_DFR, USCO_AHO)
VALUES (1, '2018-02-10', NULL),
(1, '2018-03-05', '1'),
(1, '2018-06-01', NULL),

(2, '2018-01-15', '1'),
(2, '2018-04-05', NULL),
(2, '2018-07-10', '1'),

(3, '2018-04-15', '1'),
(3, '2018-05-05', NULL),
(3, '2018-09-10', '1')

SELECT USER_KEY, USCO_DFR, USCO_AHO FROM (
SELECT USER_KEY
    ,USCO_DFR
    ,USCO_AHO
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY USER_KEY ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS RNO
FROM @BAUSCO ) A
WHERE A.USCO_AHO = A.RNO AND A.USCO_AHO = 1
```

The result is as below,

```
USER_KEY    USCO_DFR                  USCO_AHO
2           2018-01-15 00:00:00.000   1
3           2018-04-15 00:00:00.000   1
```

Comment: your query doesn't return anything. Empty table.

Comment: @FrenkyB I've included the complete code along with the result

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a little overkill to break out the analytic functions, but they're just so darn handy...

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT
    *,
    MAX(USCO_DFR) OVER (PARTITION BY USER_KEY) AS MAX_DFR
  FROM
    @BAUSCO
) T
WHERE
  T.USCO_AHO = '1' 
  AND T.USCO_DFR = T.MAX_DFR
```

Results:

```
| USER_KEY |             USCO_DFR | USCO_AHO |              MAX_DFR |
|----------|----------------------|----------|----------------------|
|        2 | 2018-07-10T00:00:00Z |        1 | 2018-07-10T00:00:00Z |
|        3 | 2018-09-10T00:00:00Z |        1 | 2018-09-10T00:00:00Z |
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @BAUSCO TABLE
(
    USER_KEY INT,
    USCO_DFR DATETIME,
    USCO_AHO CHAR(1)
)

INSERT @BAUSCO(USER_KEY, USCO_DFR, USCO_AHO)
VALUES (1, '2018-02-10', NULL),
(1, '2018-03-05', '1'),
(1, '2018-06-01', NULL),

(2, '2018-01-15', NULL),
(2, '2018-04-05', NULL),
(2, '2018-07-10', '1'),

(3, '2018-04-15', NULL),
(3, '2018-05-05', NULL),
(3, '2018-09-10', '1')

select * from @BAUSCO a
where USCO_DFR=(select MAX(USCO_DFR) from @BAUSCO b where a.USER_KEY=b.USER_KEY )
    and USCO_AHO=1
```

[IMAGE LINK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaXic.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT A.* FROM @BAUSCO A INNER JOIN
(
     SELECT USER_KEY, Max(USCO_DFR) MaxUSCO_DFR
     FROM @BAUSCO
     GROUP BY USER_KEY
) B
ON A.USER_KEY = B.USER_KEY AND A.USCO_DFR = B.MaxUSCO_DFR
WHERE A.USCO_AHO = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In a simple SQL, using GROUP BY with sub query, you can get the expected result:

```
SELECT Q.USER_KEY, Q.USCO_DFR, B.USCO_AHO
FROM (
    SELECT USER_KEY, MAX(USCO_DFR) AS USCO_DFR
    FROM @BAUSCO
    GROUP BY USER_KEY
) Q 
JOIN @BAUSCO B ON B.USER_KEY = Q.USER_KEY AND B.USCO_DFR = Q.USCO_DFR
WHERE B.USCO_AHO = '1'
```

[**Working demo on db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d757211f28a6c32c28aa1d6c439d30e2)